# Where is the attribute information stored for partitioned table in kdb

Tags: kdb

I have a partitioned table in kdb which is partitioned on data and parted on tick column.
**Where is the attribute metadata that the table is parted on `tick` column being stored in kdb?**

Example -

```
t:([] tick:10?`amzn`fb`goog; px:10?10.; vol:10?1000) / Create a table in memory
.Q.dpft[`:db;2023.10.01;`tick;`t] / Partitioned on date and parted on tick
```

Now loading the db in q session

```
\l db
meta t
c   | t f a
----| -----
date| d    
tick| s   p
px  | f    
vol | j
```

If I look at the .d file of the table it consists on only the column order.

```
get `:2023.10.01/t/.d
`tick`px`vol
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right in that the attribute information is stored in the column/file and can be seen using a get:

```
get `:2023.10.01/t/tick
`p#`sym$`p#`amzn`amzn`fb`fb`fb`fb`fb`goog`goog`goog
```

Under the covers it is represented by a single byte as per this example: https://code.kx.com/q/kb/serialization/#integer-vector

```
q)-8!`p#1 2j
0x010000001e00000007030200000001000000000000000200000000000000

bytes       semantics
0x01        little endian
000000  
1e000000    message length (30)
07          type (long vector)
03          attributes (00 – none, 01 – s, 02 – u, 03 – p, 04 – g)
02000000    vector length (2)
0100000000000000    first item, an 8 byte long (1)
0200000000000000    second item, an 8 byte long (2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Got the answer, **the attribute information for a column is stored in the splayed file for that column.**

```
get `:2023.10.01/t/tick
`p#`sym$`p#`amzn`amzn`fb`fb`fb`fb`fb`goog`goog`goog
```

Similarly if the table has a sorted or any other attribute applied on `tick` column. Then that information will stored in the same splayed file for that column.

**Testing with sorted attribute**

```
t:([] tick:asc 10?`amzn`fb`goog; px:10?10.; vol:10?1000) / table sorted on tick
`:db/2023.10.01/t/ set .Q.en[`:db;t] / create partition
```

**Check the tick column content**

```
get `:db/2023.10.01/t/tick
`s#`sym$`s#`amzn`amzn`amzn`amzn`fb`fb`fb`goog`goog`goog
```

**meta of the table**

```
meta t
c   | t f a
----| -----
date| d    
tick| s   s
px  | f    
vol | j
```

Hence, .d is the only meta data file which is being stored in kdb which stores the column order, rest all the information related to the data is placed in the data/column file.